# Create class instance within a class

Tags: python, class, nested, instance

I have a nested class in python for instance:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1
    class B():
        def __init__(self, attr2):
            self.attr2 = attr2
```

What I want to achieve is that instance **b** for class **B**, will be like a data structure of instance **a** for class **A**

However, it seems that **b** is not associate with **a**.

How can I achieve that?

**Update**:

What I want to do is something like the picture shown below, which is a java program object initialization:
[image]

It seems that user contains userID and Password and it is associated with the serviceOrder object.

Comment: What does "will be like a data structure" mean?

Comment: *"I have a nested class in python"* - why?

Comment: For instance, b contains 2 other attributes, and b is like another big attribute to a. Sorry to be so newbie, I am not sure I expressed myself correctly. Hope you understand.

Comment: Could you provide a less... abstract example? `A` and `B` are meaningless names, so it's hard to get to grips with what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Are you **kidding me?!** Not even a screenshot of code, but a *photo of a screen of code?!* Why on earth did you think that would be appropriate? Code is text - for the love of everything *include it as such*!

Comment: Cos that is not my picture, and is passed to me by another man.... @jonrsharpe

Comment: So make the same complaint to them, or write it out yourself - if you don't have the information, don't ask the question. Photographs of text content **are not acceptable**.

Comment: Note also that *"something like this Java"* isn't particularly helpful; could you explain **in words** what it is that you want your code to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is rarely any reason to nest classes in Python. I *think* what you mean is to have an instance of `B` as an attribute of an instance of `A`, which is easy to do:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.b = B(attr2)

class B():
    def __init__(self, attr2):
        self.attr2 = attr2
```

Comment: I have update the question, please refer to the update. Thank you@Daniel  Roseman

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood your preferred solution has already been provided in [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650904/2437514).

However, if for some reason you or someone else really does need to nest class `B` inside of `A`, you can do that this way:

```
class A(): 
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.b = A.B(attr2) # NOTE: refer to class B via ``A.B``
    class B():
        def __init__(self, attr2):
            self.attr2 = attr2
```

The reason you have to do it this way is `B` is a class attribute of `A`. It is no different than any other class-level attribute, and therefore accessing the attribute must be done via the owning class, e.g.:

```
MyClass.my_attr
# OR:
getattr(MyClass, 'my_attr')
# OR:
MyClass.__dict__['my_attr']
# etc. etc.
```

Note this is true even when you're inside of the owning class:

```
class MyClass():
    class_attr = 1
    def get_class_attr(self):
        # return class_attr would raise a NameError
        return MyClass.class_attr # no error

MyClass().get_class_attr() # 1
```